# Define a set T and prove that $\theta$ is given by the formulas:

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $T = \mathbb{R}^2 - \{(x,y)|y=0,x\leq 0\}$. If $(x,y)\in T$, express $x$ and $y$ in polar coordinates: $x=r\cos\theta$ , $y=r\sin\theta$, where $r>0$ and $-\pi<\theta<\pi$. Prove that $\theta$ is given by the formulae:

$$\begin{align}\theta = 
\begin{cases}
\arctan(y/x)\quad &\text{if } x>0; \\
\pi/2 \quad &\text{if }x=0;\\
\arctan(y/x) + \pi \quad &\text{if }x<0; \\
\end{cases}\end{align}$$

Of course that if i divide $\sin\theta$/$\cos\theta$ = $\tan\theta$ i will get $y/x$. Then, applying the inverse function i will get arctan$(y/x)=\theta$.

But how do i actually prove the formulae above?

Answer (score 1):

$T$ can be defined by the following polar parametric equations

$x=r\cos(\theta)$ and

$y=r\sin(\theta)$ with

$r>0$ and $\;-\frac{\pi}{2}<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$.

we check that

$$\frac{y}{x}=\frac{r\sin(\theta)}{r\cos(\theta)}=tan(\theta)$$

or

$$\theta=arctan(\frac{y}{x})$$

since $$\theta\in(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}).$$

Comment: Ok. But how do i prove that for $x<0$ i must define $\theta$ as arctan$(y/x)$ +$\pi$? Or, why is it necessary?

Comment: @stdio.h $x$ is $>0$